# Feeding a breaker panel through a 120v outlet

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, 120-240v

Okay...so I have a shack we use during events. It has 240 panel inside that feeds 3 florescent lights and plug in. It was powered through a 6awg power cord that plugged in to an outlet off of a power pole. We've had to move it and to save money I wired in a 20amp 120 plug in. Thinking 120 will feed a few lights. Well when I plug in the cord to be the panel (breakers are off in the shack panel) it kicks out the breaker from the source. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your wiring, sounds like hot/neutral might be switched.

Comment: We'll need some pictures of your panels and outlets. You make it sound like you're using a cable with two male plugs on it ..... hope your not.

Comment: Yes using a double male cord. Not ideal but all I had on hand. Plan on switching it.

Comment: I wired my end up right but it is very probable the source power is flipped. I'll try that

Comment: Please read https://hothardware.com/news/cpsc-startling-electrocution-warning-cables-sold-amazon

Comment: If you are using a dangerous type of cord, how do we know you "wired my end up right"? Seriously. Provide specifics - what kind of panel, what connections are made from the receptacle to the panel, etc. Plus, you can wire up an *inlet* and be totally legal *and safer* for very little more money.

Comment: Literally both ends of a cord are hot when plugged in whether it's a female or male end. That's not my problem. Like I said I'm going to switch it. As crip said the source outlet is probably wired backwards from mine

Comment: The problem is that casually touching the end of a live male to male cable is deadly. Female end requires some real talent to become deadly.

Comment: I must be dead then

Comment: Wait, before, was it hard-wired into the power stand, or did it plug into a large outlet like a NEMA 14-50?   I mean there's no problem with your subpanel being fed by a cord-and-plug, just the prongy plug need to be on the side that *takes* power not the side that *gives* it.  This is cheap and easy to do, it just needs doing and we can help with that.

Comment: Thats correct Harper. So you're saying just hard wire the extension cord into both  hot lugs in the panel?

Answer (score 3):

Take a 3-prong extension cord that is 14 AWG or 12 AWG.

Lop off the **socket** (female/holey thing) end and throw it in the trash.

Take it to an electrical supply and get a compression strain relief/grommet that fits the cord.

Knock out a 1/2" knockout on the bottom of your subpanel.

Bring the cord+grommet into the subpanel.

*Separate neutral bar from ground bar in the subpanel.*

Cord ground to ground bar.

Cord neutral to neutral bar.

Remove any old cords currently hooked to the hot lugs.  For this cord, pigtail hot to both main lugs.  Make sure you do not have any MWBCs in the panel.

**Cheap, safe, legal.**  NEC 400.7.

Comment: Make sure the extension cord is actually the correct thickness. A cheap extension cords are typically undersized.